# Attempting to update the 'UEFI dbx' package crashes my system

Tags: apt, updates, uefi

I was getting an annoying "failed to update metadata for lvfs" in the Kubuntu 20.04 'discover' app. This was causing no problems, but I found a site that recommended fixing it by running `fwupdmgr --force refresh`

After doing that, the system rebooted on the next attempt to install updates - and would either reboot or just hang the updater any time I tried to update. So, figuring I had somehow installed a bad package on my system, and because I was running 20.04, I decided to move forward and install 22.04.1.  I installed it into a new partition, and it seemed to have fixed it (i.e., I was able to perform some initial updates on the new system). But the next round of updates caused the crash again. I noticed that one of the updates was "UEFI dbx - update to version 217". If I deselect that one, all the other updates run okay. But if I try to run that update, the system reboots.

Have I trashed something.  Since I'm running a new, clean OS in a new partition, I'm guessing the initial fwupdmgr attempted to do some kind of UEFI firmware update - so something may be trashed in firmware that affects more than just the older OS where I ran fwupdmgr (unless the problem is something in /home - I'm using the same /home partition in the new OS). Am I screwed - or is there a way to fix this? I suppose I could disable updates to UEFI dbx in Discover and hope that that gets around it... For now, I disabled the 'lvfs' firmware update service repository, and UEFI dbx no longer shows up as an available update. Is that kosher?

By the way, the package description for UEFI dbx says it has to do with updating secure boot signatures. I have secure boot disabled and Kubuntu installed without the shim (I think). I guess maybe that's why my system still works.

Comment: Upgrading the OS is NEVER a good way to fix a problem. The problem just carries over. It may not happen right away but it will.

Comment: @David.  I wasn't attempting to fix my OS by updating it.  I loaded a new version into a separate partition - partly to see if my partition or my UEFI memory was corrupted.

Comment: That info should be in the question. Please EDIT the question and add it. People can only respond to what you put in the question.